What's that movie about baldness cure?
There is this movie in which two companies exist in the field of creating shampoo. One company  finds the baldness cure, and the other company tries to steal it. 
The manager of the first company creates a plan to prevent the stealing process. The plan works like this. A team of experts of hired to act as thieves and they pretend to work for the competitor company, and they pretend that the formula is stolen.
The manager of the competitor company (bad manager) celebrates this by announcing that "they've found baldness cure", while the manager of the first company has started production with the correct formula.
I don't know anything about the movie.

Duplicity might be what you're looking for.

Just what I wanted. Thanks :)

No problem. Please make sure to mark my answer :)
